# Exporting data to excel faster

Tags: vb.net, performance, excel, export-to-excel, read-write

I want to export data to excel.I also want to perform functionality like cell merge,cell border,text underline. But the exporting becomes slower if because of these alignment merge etc for large data. Here is a sample of excel which i do [click here](http://incometaxsoft.com/pdf/supertraders.xlsx)

I saw some articles relate to excel export using cell by cell export,using array to a range of cells etc.

Earlier i had problems with slow data export to an word file by using word object which is of about 25-35 pages.It was taking 1 to 2 mins.For this problem i used rtf file format without using word object by which i was able to export in some seconds.I used file I/O to write data.
So can i use similar kind of any excel file format aware methods which can export to excel faster with functions like cell merge , alignment,border etc ?

Comment: see the frameworks listed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264677/best-library-to-generate-excel-and-charts-in-excel

Comment: Can i write changes to the excel file by changing the content of excel file.I mean if we can change the file content then file writing will be faster.But for this excel file format should be known

Comment: Rename an excel file to .zip and you'll see the format. It's doable - but IMHO way too much effort as the format is complex.

Comment: @PeterAlbert Yes fomat is too complex. But is there any existing code which does it or gives hint about doing this?

Comment: Yes, the frameworks listed in the question linked above...

Comment: @PeterAlbert But does those frameworks provide their source code?

Comment: I don't know - shouldn't be too hard to find out though... ;-)